# How to set a background image in the LoginOverlay

Tags: css, image, background, vaadin

Simple thing.  I need to use my own background for LoginOverlay in Vaadin 23.
I tried crazy magic with stuff like this

```
vaadin-login-overlay-wrapper
vaadin-login-backdrop-wrapper
```

and it did not work.

Comment: Please be more specific, what you have tried (e.g. add the source and to what fies you have changed).

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `vaadin-login-overlay-wrapper.css` in `frontend/<your theme>/components`

Then you can set the background image

```
:host [part="brand"] {
    background-image: url("images/login-banner.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-x: center;
}
```

Comment: excellent asnwer...I was so close... but for the fact that I had way more code in  vaadin-login-overlay-wrapper.css in frontend/<your theme>/components  that caused the issues EXCELLENT ANSWER thank you

Comment: Besides to @Simon Martinelli's answer, I suggest referring to the following official documentation for a deeper insight into styling any components within Lumo or any customized theme of your own:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/custom-theme/creating-custom-theme/#vaadin-component-styles

Comment: @VaadinUser normally when an answer like this helps you, you can mark it as the accepted answer by using that green check mark on the left side of the answer ;) This the correct way of appreciation as others can find out about what was the problem much easier.